# Insecure form post value validating

Tags: php, sql, forms, security

Currently I'm using a form to post a "comment" and save it in the database there are two hidden fields, one to check what component the comment is made on and the other hidden field is the comment number. But I found a exploit in my own form. If I go into the developer console I can change them to either crosspost the comments to a other form, or to something that doesn't exist, this doesn't really matter, nor the fact that I can change the number the comment is, because it still works properly if there's a comment with the same number.

```
<form action="/index.php?option=com_comments&view=comment&row=<?= $row ?>&table=<?= $table ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="row" value="<?= $row ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="table" value="<?= $table ?>" />

<textarea type="text" name="text" class="control control--textarea control-group__control" placeholder="<?= translate('Add new comment here ...') ?>" id="new-comment-text"></textarea>
<br />
<input class="leader btn btn--theme control-row__trigger" type="submit" value="<?= translate('Comment') ?>"/>
```

But the issue is that when I go to the console and I add  and then submit the form I can actually override the value and post as that I'm someone else. Which is obviously not intended behaviour to be able to post as someone else. I can't seem to find a way to validate the value of created_by before the post is being send, because if I put it in a hidden input field too it can be changed just as well. What can I do to make this secure?

EDIT: The posting is done automatically and I literally can't change anything about it because of the Framework we're using. And it overrides the proper default behaviour. A better way to phrase my question would be, can I prevent a user from adding a extra hidden input field to post extra values? Should I post form post check everytime if the post includes a created_by and if it does change it to the current profile_id?

Malicious code changed via developer console

```
<form action="/index.php?option=com_comments&amp;view=comment&amp;row=2&amp;table=blogs_blogs&amp;created_by=6" method="post" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="a0b15d3664d7bc0e0e40675095fec014">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="a0b15d3664d7bc0e0e40675095fec014">
    <input type="hidden" name="row" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="created_by" value="6">
    <input type="hidden" name="table" value="blogs_blogs">

    <textarea type="text" name="text" class="control control--textarea control-group__control" placeholder="Add new comment here ..." id="new-comment-text"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input class="leader btn btn--theme control-row__trigger" type="submit" value="Comment">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that shows us how created_by is being generated?

Comment: shouldn't this  `<?= $row ?>` be `<?php echo $row; ?>` out of curiosity

Comment: @krushiovida it does same thing.

Comment: @RyanVincent  derp. derpy. derp. time for bed... gracias.

Comment: So I can specify what table to write to but if I don't like in this example it knows what table I want to write it to by "magic" which is actually how it's explained for the framework (Nooku) that we're using. What happens is that normally the input for created by isn't send with the post request and then it just takes the current logged in user_id and puts that in created_by which makes sense. But by adding a hidden input myself I am overriding this behaviour. I need to know how to make this secure so the user can't be messing with it.

Comment: Editted code to show what it's basically doing behind the scenes, because it's in com_comments it knows what database it should be posting to.

Comment: store state in server session or HMAC the info on the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule #1 in web application security: **Never trust the client**

If the user is logged in, store the user's id in the session and only use that identifier to store his/her records in the database.

Plus, you should implement a mechanism to prevent [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) (cross site request forgery) in your form. Because I can't see that it does.

Comment: That's already what it's doing but we're using a HMVC framework called Nooku that has certain "magic" elements, and by adding a <input> myself for Created_By it overrides the correct function, because me sending it with the post goes over the default handling when it's not send. It's already just taking the currently logged in person and putting it there normally, but it's overriden when I add a input myself.

Comment: Thank you for the edit of your question and specifying more information about your environment. Nice to see that you added _token to your form. Again even if the user adds a new hidden input field to try to overwrite the created_by id, your form controller should prevent this by only using the user's id from the session. Surely you can overwrite the default behavior of your framework (subclass etc.) If not, then this is IMHO a security vulnerability in the framework and you should contact the developers.

Comment: So there is no direct way to detect the adding of extra input fields after the page is generated. Would there be a alternative to the use of hidden input fields? Because it seems like the amount of validation I have to do then for every possible field the user can enter is quite a lot then.

Also the possible malicious user doesn't know the database structure of course so it's a bit harder for him, and some fields I highly doubt would be "guessable" but I guess I can't consider the fact that someone will never guess the name of the column a secure feature. Anyways thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session or cookies together with database

```
[php]

$userHash = $db->prepare('SELECT user_hash FROM user WHERE id = :uId')->scalar([':uId' => $this->getUserId()]);

if (!empty($_SESSION['userHash']) && $_SESSION['userHash'] == $userHash) {
    // process form
    // generate new user hash
} else {
    die('!HACKER!');
}
```

Instead of user ID you can use session ID.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding this check to the behaviour that's applied before it's actually posted to the server

```
public function createdbycheck(Library\CommandContext $context)
{
    $context->request->data->created_by = null;
}
```

Just sets it to NULL, and then it's handled by the default behaviour.